# Can't mount partition image "ntfs-3g-mount: mount failed: Permission denied"

Tags: mount, permissions, ntfs, disk-image, ntfs-3g

I used Disks tool to make an image of a partition:

[image: Create Partition Image]

Then tried to mount it with Disk Image Mounter:

[image: Disk Image Mounter]

I enter my password twice:

[image: add loop device]
[image: mount loop device]

Then it fails with this error message:

> Unable to mount OLD SYSTEM_DRV
>
> Error mounting /dev/loop1 at /media/endolith/OLD SYSTEM_DRV:
>   Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o
>   "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/loop1"
>   "/media/endolith/OLD SYSTEM_DRV"' exited with non-zero exit status
>   21: ntfs-3g-mount: mount failed: Permission denied

Why is permission denied and how do I fix this?

Comment: Try  `sudo chown 1000: /media/endolith/OLD SYSTEM_DRV`. Note that the folder must exist already.

Comment: @mook765 Hmm, it doesn't exist.  I get asked for my password twice, actually.  Once for setting up the loop device and once for mounting it.

Comment: @mook765 And if I create it and then try your command I get `chown: invalid spec: '1000:'`

Comment: OK, remove the created folder. The folder will be created automatically during mount and it seems here is not the problem. Please check the ownership of the image-file. Could be the problem that the image is owned by root. If that is the case change ownership of the file with `sudo chown endolith:endolith /path/to/your/image_file`. (I see, chown-command doesn't accept user-id).

Comment: @mook765 `sudo mkdir /mnt/SYSTEM_DRV`
    `sudo mount -t ntfs -o loop "Disk Image.img" /mnt/SYSTEM_DRV` works fine, for the record

Comment: This way you mount with root-privileges

Comment: I'm trying, I created a disk-image of my Windows-partition. Just right now i get the same error-message like you, will need some time to check more...

Comment: @mook765 Well if you get the same error message, I guess my bug report is valid:  https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=98050

Comment: I think too it is a bug, I changed ownership of the image-file from me to root an back, always the same...